# ¿Queremos banners de ayuda para usuarios?

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, estado-completado, centro-de-ayuda

### Editado al 10/12

Doy por concluida la votación y tenemos que elaborar una pregunta con las respuestas que se van a publicar en los banners.

### Original

Hablando con el CM [Nicolas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) sobre algunos problemas que tienen algunos usuarios nuevos y no tan nuevos para usar el sitio, él me comentó que en SO ru, muestran unos banners para todos los usuarios con información rápida de cómo usar el sitio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde está la cara de Nicolas son los banners:

El banner de arriba, habla sobre como decir gracias a un post.
El de la derecha dice cómo hacer preguntas sobre la moderación del sitio.

Estos dos banners llevan a las siguientes publicaciones:

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7124/6

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7122/6

Para que quede claro, esto sería como poner nuestras propias publicidades en el sitio.

Para ello, necesitaríamos crear dos preguntas en Meta. Una de ellas, va a ser a donde sean dirigidos los banner, que en el caso de SO ru es:

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7020/317616

Y la otra es sobre cómo haríamos este proceso, como crear los tips, y eso, aunque pienso que en este caso, ya teniendo el ejemplo de SO ru, no sé si sería tan necesario.

Esto no involucra tanto trabajo de nuestro lado. Las publicaciones son cortas y las explicaciones sencillas. Pero sí va a cambiar el "perfil" de cómo se ve el sitio..

Y necesitamos un modelo para que salga en las publicidades :p

La idea de este post es decir si estamos o no de acuerdo. Voy a poner dos respuestas para ello.

Comment: Aunque los manuales digan como elaborar una buena pregunta , no es facil realizar primera la pregunta;  es incercia pura la que nos obliga, luego otros usuarios con poderes de revision acomodan la pregunta , y el usuario a pesar de que su pregunta este bien , va cargando con los malos habitos , he visto usuarios con 500 o mas que aun no saben como preguntar, y siempre que es mejora cuenten con mi apoyo

Comment: Grandísima iniciativa, puede ser muy útil. Ahora nos tocará redactarlo de forma ágil, para que no parezca un tocho post del que nadie pase de la primera línea.

Comment: @fedorqui fijate que los post en RU son cortitos y al toque... solo lo estrictamente necesario...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sí, estoy de acuerdo con que mostremos la cara de alguien para ayudar!!!

Implementado en [Consejos sobre cómo usar el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3761/83)

Comment: ¿Se va a mostrar tu cara Gonzalo? :-) hehe

Answer (score 6):

No, por favor, ya es demasiado complejo, y un cartel seria peor.