# Consejos sobre cómo usar el sitio

Tags: discusión, anuncios-de-ayuda

Stack Overflow es un sitio bastante complicado tanto desde el punto de vista técnico como ideológico.

A veces para los nuevos usuarios es difícil entender que esto no es un foro como los que se acostumbra a ver en internet.

Tienen problemas para saber cómo editar sus preguntas, dónde dejar comentarios y dónde no, cómo responder y qué responder, así como de qué forma agradecer a aquellos que los ayudan.

A veces fallan completando un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), o ponen preguntas sobre ejercicios sin mostrar que hicieron, o ponen directamente código sin explicar su error.

Para ello, estos consejos pueden ser mucho mejor que llevarlos a páginas que pueden ser más confusas de leer si son más largas que 10 renglones y una imagen.

En el modelo Stack Overflow, la capacitación de los “novatos” recae sobre los participantes más experimentados. Para hacer que la capacitación sea más efectiva / automatizada, reunimos en esta pregunta pequeñas respuestas: consejos sobre el trabajo del sitio.

Esta pregunta está relacionada con la votación iniciada en [¿Queremos banners de ayuda para usuarios?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3749/324)

Comment: Muy útil para los nuevos usuario, gracias Gonzalo!

Comment: Cabe aclarar que cualquier puede agregar tips que sean faciles de leer. O solo poner la idea y entre todos lo arreglamos

Answer (score 36):

### Marcar la respuesta como aceptada te da +2 en la reputación.

Si en tu pregunta recibes una respuesta completa que solucionó tu problema, márcala como aceptada pulsando en la marca de verificación (✔).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fíjate debajo de la puntuación de la respuesta que hay una tilde. Marca solo una (el sistema no te va a dejar marcar más de una). Con esto, además, se considera que estás agradeciendo a quien agregó la respuesta, y le servirá a futuros usuarios para saber que a ti te ayudó a resolver el problema o duda que planteaste en la pregunta.

Se te otorgarán 2 puntos de reputación, y el que escribió esa respuesta recibirá 15.

Para más información, mira [¿Qué significa cuando una respuesta es "aceptada"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)  y también [¿Qué es la reputación? ¿Cómo se gana (y se pierde)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 36):

### No tengo reputación para dejar un comentario, pero quiero decir algo

A veces, queremos comentar en una pregunta, pero dado que somos nuevos aquí, no tenemos la [reputación suficiente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), porque no tenemos los 50 puntos requeridos.

Entonces la recomendación es: ten paciencia.

Hay formas de ganar reputación fácilmente: haciendo buenas preguntas, aceptando las respuestas que te dieron, ayudando a mantener limpio el sitio editando preguntas y respuestas.

***No*** uses la sección respuestas para dejar tu comentario. Si la pregunta está incompleta y tu respuesta no es completa, entonces no le va a servir a futuros usuarios.

Comment: Desafortunadamente tenemos muy pocos moderadores activos del sitio, por experiencia personal usando la plataforma Stack Overflow comento que se pueden otorgar los permisos de comentar a personas destacadas en específico, por ejemplo, digamos, si eres el creador del framework del que preguntan.

Comment: Otra opción que no aliento debido a la falta de moderadores activos es que si tienes algo totalmente importante que comentar y no puedes hacerlo por que aún no tienes ese privilegio lo hagas como respuesta, los moderadores con más privilegios nos encargaremos de eliminar esa respuesta y de poner tu comentario o darte el permiso de comentar si es que podemos otorgarlo a nuestra consideración.

Comment: @RuslanLópez no entiendo tus comentarios.. El segundo es justamente lo que queremos evitar. Y el primero no se a que te referis.

Comment: Un excelente solución pienso yo que ademas aportaría al `onboarding` seria permitir comentar, pero después motivarle a completar los 50 puntos en menos de 12 horas o el comentario se eliminara, si es votado como útil agregar 72 horas al plazo. ( Actualmente existe las medallas, pero podría existir una barra de progreso hasta los 50 puntos donde se den las tareas a realizar para lograrlos )

Comment: Yo opino que no se le deberia prohibir al usuario poder comentar si no tiene 50 puntos, pues que gana el usuario con eso?, que ganan las demas personas con que un usuario no pueda comentar?, se supone hay algo llamado libre expresion, y aunque aqui no aplique del todo (hay un normativo de lenguaje por ejemplo), considero que es terrible quitarle ese privilegio a los nuevos usuarios, pues solo estamos fomentando a que los usuarios creen malas preguntas para ganar reputacion (porque son nuevos), o directamente que pongan respuestas para comentar pues no se les permite comentar.

Comment: @diego es interesante tu proposicion. Pero seria mejor que cuando el comentario reciva un voto en ves de aumentar el plazo, se quede por asi decirlo: Permanentemente.

Answer (score 35):

### No agregues respuestas para completar tu pregunta, edita tu pregunta

Todo en el sitio es editable, por todos los usuarios. De esa forma, el sitio se mantiene limpio y sin ruido.

Si hiciste una pregunta y necesitas agregar información, no uses los comentarios para explayarte, edita tu pregunta y agrega los detalles que se te están pidiendo.

Para ello, presiona sobre el botón editar y podrás modificar tu pregunta todas las veces que necesites:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El mismo está ubicado apenas finaliza tu pregunta, debajo de las etiquetas que le agregaste a la misma.

Ten en cuenta que, como es un sitio colaborativo, ¡podés hacerlo en cualquier pregunta y respuesta! Sin embargo, hasta que tengas 2000 puntos de reputación alguien va a tener que aceptar tu edición (y si es aceptada, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación).

Para mas información: [¿Por qué puede la gente editar mis mensajes? ¿Cómo funciona el trabajo de edición?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) y [editar preguntas y respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)

Answer (score 24):

### ¡Tengo una duda sobre cómo funciona el sitio!

Para las dudas sobre el funcionamiento del sitio, si no lograste encontrar una respuesta en la [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help), existe [Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Alli, las preguntas son más libres, el formato es más relajado y se admiten discusiones.

Sin embargo, las únicas preguntas válidas son sobre el funcionamiento del sitio (motivos de cierre de preguntas, ediciones mal hechas, pedidos de caracteristicas nuevas, dudas sobre la moderación... entre otras cosas).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡No dudes en hacer la pregunta allí si algo no te convence sobre el funcionamiento del sitio!

Para mas información: [¿Qué es "meta" y cómo funciona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Answer (score 23):

#### Colabora con el sitio revisando lo que otros escribieron

Si te fijas, en la parte superior hay un icono que te lleva a las [colas de revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review).

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez allí, encontrarás distintas colas:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yendo a cualquiera de ellas colaboras con el sitio de varias maneras:

- Puliendo los diamantes en bruto que dejan los nuevos usuarios.
- Decidiendo si una pregunta tiene la calidad suficiente.
- Revisando las ediciones que otros usuarios sugirieron.
- Dando una segunda oportunidad a preguntas que se modificaron para que ahora ya puedan ser abiertas.

En fin, dedicando unos pocos minutos puedes mejorar la experiencia de los que, como tú hace tiempo, entran en Stack Overflow en español por primera vez en busca de una respuesta a sus problemas. De la misma manera, consigues que el sitio tenga respuestas de mayor calidad.

Puedes leer más al respecto en:

- [Privilegios: Acceso a las colas de revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)
- [Privilegios: Acceso a herramientas de moderación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)