# ¿ Sabemos lo que significa aceptar una respuesta?

Tags: discusión

Lo estoy observando en muchos sitios; sin ir mas lejos, en la pregunta [Consejos sobre como usar el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3761/19610) (justo aquí al lado :-)

En la segunda respuesta, la primera línea dice: [`Marcar la respuesta correcta te da +2 en la reputación.`](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/19610)

Estoy en franco desacuerdo con esa expresión, que, insisto, la he visto en muchas partes, principalmente como comentario. En [el recorrido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/tour) se indica, claramente:

> La persona que formula la pregunta puede marcar una respuesta como “aceptada”.
>   
>   **Aceptar una respuesta no quiere decir que sea la mejor, solo quiere decir que le sirvió a la persona que formuló la pregunta.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Encuentro la expresión `respuesta correcta` como directamente **equívoca**, así como varias expresiones relacionadas: ¿ porqué en 2 respuestas correctas, 1 es **mejor** que otra ?

Pongo un ejemplo con esta pregunta: [¿Cómo detectar paridad de un numero sin el operador %?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/124750/19610), en la que *casualmente* (ejem ejem) tengo publicada una respuesta.

1. Si una respuesta es *correcta* ... ¿ las demás son *incorrectas* ?
2. Si las demás **no** son incorrectas ... ¿ porqué solo 1 se puede marcar como *correcta* ?
3. El tiempo pasa. En la pregunta del ejemplo, mi respuesta fue **la última** en publicarse. ¿ Una solución **mas actual** convierte en *incorrectas* a las soluciones anteriores ? Y fue la última en el mismo día. ¿ Que pasará dentro de 5 años ?

Por casos como ese, son por los que planteo esta pregunta: **cambiemos el término `correcto`** en todos los sitios en los que sea posible, y abstengámonos de usarla en nuestros futuros comentarios y/o respuestas.

¿ Que opina la comunidad ?

Comment: correcta no seria que soluciono el problema? el termino te parece confuso? si no soluciono el problema, no seria correcta.

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo. Algo puede ser correcto sin ser ideal, ni perfecto, ni siquiera adecuado. Pero no hay que hilar tan fino. Una respuesta puede ser *correcta* **hoy**, y mañana alguien publica una respuesta basándose en algo nuevo, desconocido con anterioridad. ¿ cual de ambas respuestas es la correcta ?

Comment: La que solucione el problema.. puede que las dos lo solucionen, pero es a criterio de OP decidir cual le soluciono a él el problema.. ojo, nunca se hablo de ideal ni perfecto.. solo de solucionar el problema...

Comment: Pues eso es lo que estoy diciendo: `correcto` no es el termino adecuado, y se presta a malentendidos. Estoy editando para colocar un ejemplo.

Comment: ah dale.. genial.. no estaria en desacuerdo con correcto, pero dale para adelante!

Comment: @gbianchi Listo, editado.

Comment: Opino que es mas _correcto_ "Respuesta aceptada". Puede hacer varias respuestas correctas, pero solo una es la aceptada.

Comment: Yo también creo que es mejor usar respuesta *aceptada* porque es lo que son, respuestas aceptadas y solo indica que al OP le sirvió, nada más.

Comment: De hecho, simplemente es "en algún momento el autor de la pregunta consideró que esto solucionaba su problema". Todos hemos visto mil casuísticas del tipo que la respuesta era un apañillo, que aceptó porque sí, etc etc. Siempre que busco algo y veo una respuesta aceptada miro más abajo si la primera respuesta no aceptada tiene más votos, pues me fío más del criterio de la comunidad que del de una persona a secas :)

Answer (score 5):

Sin buscar situaciones en las que el tiempo influya, se me ocurre una que he visto varias veces:

1. El OP hace una pregunta con un error en su código. El error no es evidente
2. Alguien propone una solución que no es más que un parche que enmascara el error. Aparentemente el código funciona ahora correctamente.
3. OP **acepta** la respuesta.
4. La respuesta correcta llega posteriormente, pero el OP no está interesado en revisarla.

Por tanto hay una respuesta correcta y una respuesta **aceptada**.

Comment: Correcto. Estamos de acuerdo pues, en dejar de usar `respuesta correcta` para referirnos a `respuesta aceptada` :-)