# ¿Debo borrar mi respuesta si se confirma que es errónea?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, eliminación-de-respuestas

El otro día respondí a una pregunta y, al rato, alguien me contestó indicando que mi respuesta era incorrecta con toda la razón del mundo.

Ya que mi respuesta no respondía correctamente a OP, la borré. Pero he estado pensando si debería haberla dejado sin borrar, aunque no fuese correcta, ya que muchas veces he buscado preguntas en Stackoverflow y he encontrado la respuesta a mi problema en respuestas no aceptadas.

Comment: Relacionada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3766/sabemos-lo-que-significa-aceptar-una-respuesta?rq=1

Comment: ¿Es la respuesta sobre tail -f?

Comment: Si, la respuesta que "insipiró" esta pregunta es esa. Aunque no era la primera vez en la que no he dado una buena respuesta. Por eso quería saber si lo mejor es borrarlas o dejarlas.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> mi respuesta era incorrecta

> he encontrado la respuesta a mi problema en respuestas no aceptadas

Incorrecta y no-aceptada no son lo mismo.

---

Si tu respuesta es incorrecta, hace más daño con su presencia que con su ausencia. Piensa que mientras tu respuesta está en estado "*borrada*" puedes editarla para mejorarla y dejarla en un estado que sea útil para ti, para quien preguntó y para futuros visitantes.

Si tu respuesta corregida es o no es aceptada, ya es trigo de otro costal.

Comment: Gracias, no sabía que se podían editar mientras estaban borradas.