# Verifiquemos las respuestas

Tags: discusión, respuesta

Últimamente me estoy encontrando mas respuestas de "*fe*", con esto me refiero a respuestas que no ofrecen una fuente/referencia o documentación. Sueltan el código y tienes cruzar los dedos para que sea correcta.

Muchas veces ademas no es ni código si no un pseudo-código que pese a que pueda mostrar la idea no va a funcionar.

Por la razón que estoy haciendo esta pregunta, es por que ademas me he encontrado mas casos en los que se dan **respuestas erróneas**. No se han informado y han redactado una respuesta que o no responde a la pregunta o da una respuesta totalmente incorrecta.

Por lo que me gustaría incitar a los nuevos usuarios a que den respuestas <strike>mas</strike> verídicas.

> ¡Demuéstrame que tienes razón y que tu respuesta es correcta!

Snippets (fiddles), documentación, enlace a otra respuesta verídica...

---

Relacionado:

[¿Debo borrar mi respuesta si se confirma que es errónea?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4462/debo-borrar-mi-respuesta-si-se-confirma-que-es-err%c3%b3nea)

[No votemos positivamente por la reputación, votemos el contenido!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4192/no-votemos-positivamente-por-la-reputaci%c3%b3n-votemos-el-contenido)

Comment: El apuro por ser el primero en contestar (incluso en preguntas no muy claras) tambien hace estragos...

Comment: Pues eso se soluciona cuando la comunidad está más activa y cura el contenido. Te agradezco de antemano el hecho de tomar un tiempo para expresar tu punto de vista, entiendo a lo que te refieres; la cantidad de preguntas cada vez aumenta e irónicamente su calidad tiende a disminuir. Lo mismo aplica a las respuestas, a veces me he topado con respuestas que solo tienen enlaces. Hace un tiempo redacté en meta https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 donde hablo sobre los ingredientes de una buena pregunta. Quizás debamos publicar ingredientes de una buena respuesta, ¿qué opinan?

Comment: @fredyfx Una iniciativa excelente

Comment: @fredyfx Sip la vi en su día tu respuesta, muy buena por cierto, gracias por enlazarla. Respecto a la propuesta que haces creo que es una gran idea.

Answer (score 3):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es un clásico, especialmente de parte de quienes inician el sitio, sin haber leído el recorrido, ni haber revisado cómo responder.

Hace como 3 meses lancé una publicación donde mencionaba [los ingredientes de una buena pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822); es momento de comentar los ingredientes de una buena respuesta, hace como 2 semanas que veo esta publicación y sin que alguien más haya respondido hasta el momento, vamos colaborando con la comunidad :D

Las **respuestas** que son **buenas** cuentan con los siguientes **ingredientes**:

1. Entiende bien el problema a resolver, es decir, no solo te mandan a instalar una librería y ya, sino que también saben el motivo de la elección de esa ruta a seguir. Hay respuestas que cuentan con alternativas y/o sugerencias para el escenario mostrado, lo cual me parece genial debido a que soluciona el problema y además expande la visión para aplicar alguna otra solución.
2. Tienen código de ejemplo explicado y/o comentado paso a paso para que cualquier usuario de cualquier nivel de experiencia pueda entender con facilidad.
3. Los enlaces que se utilizan cuentan con descripción, es decir, "aquí está la documentación de XYZ librería". Y extraen un ejemplo de algún enlace.
4. Evitan parecer SMS, respuestas de una sola línea que tranquilamente pasan por comentarios.
5. El contenido es ameno para leer, se percibe la hermandad y las ganas de colaborar y no a una persona gritando dándote órdenes (atención a las mayúsculas por favor).
6. Incluye los requisitos tales como importación de alguna librería, archivos de configuración adicionales, etc. He visto respuestas que te dan parcialmente la respuesta que necesitas siempre y cuando hagas un import de algún package, esto último es muy común en usuarios avanzados que a veces se olvidan que la comunidad tiene usuarios desde niveles "*hello wordianos*" hasta niveles avanzados que programan para la NASA con tecnología alienígena y tal.
7. Utilizan bien los formatos, saben emplear el uso de letras **negritas**, *cursivas* y el `código` también cuenta con su sangría que es un deleite para la vista. Cabe mencionar que la ortografía empleada es buena y libre de abreviaturas absurdas tales como 'xq', 'tb', 'ke'. No pasamos alrededor de 11 años en educación obligatoria, ¿o sí?
8. Nunca encuentras frases del tipo: "a mi también me pasó lo mismo", "¿alguien que pueda ayudar?", "es urgente, ¡ayuda por favor!". Venga que si la pregunta sigue sin respuesta y quieres llamar la atención de la comunidad, existe el concepto de recomenpensas que van desde +50.
9. No es edición de la pregunta donde le colocan más detalles, por favor, si van a agregar más información, existe la opción de editar la pregunta. Mantengamos el orden el sitio, por el bien de todos los que estamos y de los que vendrán.
10. Esto es opcional: Al final de la respuesta te recomienda leer bibliografía de algunos autores para profundizar el tema que estás estudiando.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Creo que te falta para mi la mas importante y a la que va dirigida esta pregunta, demostrar a los lectores que la respuesta es correcta (fiddles, documentación), en definitiva algo que la respalde.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que la cantidad de preguntas que denotan un descuido y pereza en extremo irritantes va en aumento exponencial.

> Requiero con urgencia esta funcionalidad adjunto pantallazo de un sitio cualquiera

Y los mismos que hacen esa clase de preguntas responden a otros con

> Prueba esto [link a literalmente cualquier otra cosa]

No tengo idea de cómo solucionar esto. No sé si tiene solución. No sé si necesita solucion porque ¿Será que estos son los desarrolladores del presente? Ya es trabajoso responder decentemente, más trabajoso revisar la cola de mensajes sin amargarse la vida, pero si revisamos las respuestas (máxime si pretendemos de ellas que pongan ejemplos ejecutables) creo que nos ponemos una mochila aplastante.

Answer (score 1):

En lo relativo a problemas de código, opino que las respuestas deben contener un código que funcione correctamente y que haya sido probado con un conjunto razonable de datos (que incluya casos límites).

Sin un código de respaldo, una respuesta no es tal; es simplemente una opinión. Puede ser correcta o incorrecta, pero no hay manera de saberlo, porque no se ha ofrecido ningún objeto (programa) que sea verificable.

Una respuesta debe ser correcta y también verificable. Debe incluir el código, las entradas y los resultados que prueban su corrección.

Disclaimer: Obviamente, hay preguntas de código que se resuelven con una simple indicación o modificación al código original, y que no necesitan más que eso.