# 2018: La moderación del sitio

Tags: discusión, moderación

A lot of thanks to [@lois6b](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15855/lois6b) for the translation!

---

Me gustaría compartir con vosotros las estadísticas de Stack Overflow en español.

Una característica que distingue a los sitios de la red Stack Exchange es cómo son moderados:

> Diseñamos la red Stack Exchange para ser auto-moderada, así amortizamos el coste de moderación entre miles de pequeñas porciones de esfuerzo de los propios usuarios.
> -- [Una teoría de moderación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227/83)

Aunque haya [moderadores](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/), una parte importante de la *moderación* es realizada por los usuarios, usando sus privilegios obtenidos al contribuir en el sitio. Cada uno de vosotros contribuye un poco con su tiempo y esfuerzo, y juntos conseguimos mucho más.

Entrando en un nuevo año, parémonos y reflexionemos para apreciar el trabajo que hacemos juntos. Este es el resumen de la actividad de moderación realizada los últimos 12 meses:

| Tarea | Moderadores | Comunidad¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Usuarios suspendidos² | 22 | 4 |
| Usuarios destruidos | 54 | 0 |
| Usuarios borrados | 12 | 0 |
| Usuarios contactados | 55 | 0 |
| Tareas de revisión³: Ediciones sugeridas | 828 | 20646 |
| Tareas de revisión³: Votos de reapertura | 169 | 1452 |
| Tareas de revisión³: P. de baja calidad | 267 | 15895 |
| Tareas de revisión³: Respuestas tardías | 16 | 3036 |
| Tareas de revisión³: Primeras publicaciones | 87 | 21021 |
| Tareas de revisión³: Votos de cierre | 1917 | 19553 |
| Etiquetas combinadas | 4 | 0 |
| Sinónimos de etiquetas sugeridos | 15 | 11 |
| Sinónimos de etiquetas creados | 27 | 0 |
| Cambios de resaltado de sintaxis en etiquetas | 1 | 0 |
| Preguntas desprotegidas | 2 | 0 |
| Preguntas reabiertas | 230 | 62 |
| Preguntas protegidas | 3 | 83 |
| Preguntas migradas | 11 | 1 |
| Preguntas combinadas | 5 | 0 |
| Preguntas reportadas⁴ | 42 | 9500 |
| Preguntas cerradas | 4875 | 3383 |
| Reportes de preguntas resueltos⁴ | 3434 | 6108 |
| Publicaciones desbloqueadas | 5 | 1 |
| Publicaciones recuperadas | 842 | 875 |
| Publicaciones bloqueadas | 7 | 33 |
| Publicaciones borradas⁵ | 5464 | 19805 |
| Publicaciones relanzadas | 0 | 8711 |
| Problemas derivados al equipo de CMs | 7 | 0 |
| Comentarios recuperados | 203 | 0 |
| Comentarios reportados | 7 | 804 |
| Comentarios borrados⁶ | 5168 | 11047 |
| Reportes resueltos en comentarios | 753 | 58 |
| Respuestas reportadas | 52 | 8503 |
| Reportes de respuestas resueltos | 6392 | 2163 |
| Bloques de comentarios movidos al chat | 97 | 0 |

#### Anotaciones

¹ "Comunidad" se refiere tanto a los [usuarios de Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users) *sin* [diamante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), como al usuario-bot [usuario #-1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² El sistema suspende usuarios bajo tres circunstancias: cuando el usuario es creado después de haber sido previamente suspendido, cuando el usuario es creado tras haber sido destruido por spam o reportes de categoría Abusivos o irrespetuoso, y cuando hay una suspensión que afecte trasversalmente a toda la red de Stack Exchange.

³ Esto cuenta cada revisión que fue realizada (no omitida) - como las dos revisiones necesarias para aprobar una edición cuentan como 2, el fin es indicar la frecuencia de las acciones de moderación. Esto también aplica a los reportes, etc.

⁴ Incluye reportes de cierre (pero *no* votos de cierre o re-apertura).

⁵ Esto omite los numerosos borrados que ocurren automáticamente como resultado de otra acción.

⁶ Esto incluye comentarios borrados por su propio autor ( que también cuenta para el número de reportes resueltos en comentarios).

(Muchas gracias a  [@Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) por todo el trabajo con las consultas SQL y por escribir el [post inicial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378415/564240) para la comunidad.)

Comment: Hello Nicolas! Will we have this for 2019 data? Shog has been posting it in all not-SOint sites

Comment: @fedorqui ¡Sí! Encontré consultas para obtener los datos. Solo quiero verificar con Shog que son correctos. ¡Tan pronto como reciba luz verde, publicaré los datos (espero que más tarde hoy)!

Comment: no hay prisa alguna :) ¡muchas gracias y feliz año!

Answer (score 12):

Estuve comparando los resultados de este hilo en los diferentes Stack Overflow internacionales, así como el inglés. En particular, me fijé en el tanto por ciento de revisiones que hizo el equipo de moderación respecto al que hizo la comunidad.

Aquí va:

[Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378415/1983854)

| Acciones | Moderadores | Comunidad | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tasks reviewed³: Triage queue | 13 | 1,329,907 | 0,001% |
| Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue | 1,229 | 1,177,058 | 0,104% |
| Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue | 20 | 200,214 | 0,009% |
| Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue | 71 | 631,186 | 0,011% |
| Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue | 11 | 312,478 | 0,003% |
| Tasks reviewed³: Helper queue | 2 | 40,210 | 0,004% |
| Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue | 27 | 835,061 | 0,003% |
| Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue | 611 | 440,336 | 0,13% |

[SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7567/28073)

| Acciones | Moderadores | Comunidad | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue | 125 | 17159 | 0,7% |
| Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue | 30 | 5577 | 0,53% |
| Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue | 213 | 22214 | 0,95% |
| Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue | 8 | 3189 | 0,25% |
| Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue | 95 | 17405 | 0,54% |
| Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue | 43 | 19101 | 0,22% |

[SOru](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8491/193685)

| Acciones | Moderadores | Comunidad | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Проверка: предложенные правки³ | 36 | 26719 | 0,13% |
| Проверка: голоса за переоткрытие³ | 3 | 5476 | 0,05% |
| Проверка: сообщения низкого качества³ | 97 | 54357 | 0,17% |
| Проверка: запоздалые ответы³ | 0 | 3799 | 0% |
| Проверка: первые сообщения³ | 1 | 26511 | 0,003% |
| Проверка: очередь на закрытие³ | 179 | 35174 | 0,5% |

[SOja](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2912/19559)

| Acciones | Moderadores | Comunidad | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue | 76 | 479 | 15% |
| Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue | 3 | 114 | 2,63% |
| Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue | 23 | 514 | 4,47% |
| Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue | 31 | 172 | 18% |
| Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue | 336 | 1899 | 17% |
| Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue | 13 | 921 | 1,4% |

[SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3850/83)

| Acciones | Moderadores | Comunidad | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tareas de revisión³: Ediciones sugeridas | 828 | 20646 | 4% |
| Tareas de revisión³: Votos de reapertura | 169 | 1452 | 11% |
| Tareas de revisión³: P. de baja calidad | 267 | 15895 | 1,67% |
| Tareas de revisión³: Respuestas tardías | 16 | 3036 | 0,5% |
| Tareas de revisión³: Primeras publicaciones | 87 | 21021 | 0,4% |
| Tareas de revisión³: Votos de cierre | 1917 | 19553 | 9,8% |

Los porcentajes de SOes son similares a los de SOja, pero los números absolutos de SOes son parecidos a los de SOru y SOpt, en los que los porcentajes son mucho menores. Es fácil advertir, pues, que el equipo de moderación carga con un porcentaje elevadísimo de trabajo en las colas en comparación con sitios similares.

Podría analizarse también otras métricas como "preguntas reabiertas" o "reportes de respuestas resueltos", que *grosso modo* vienen a reiterar que los moderadores cargan con un excesivo trabajo.

Si metemos en la ecuación los [datos que Mariano (siempre añorado) expuso sobre cuánta gente revisa](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3212/83), vemos que efectivamente **hay demasiada poca gente revisando**.

Por tanto, creo que:

- los moderadores deberían tener menos peso en estas colas, para hacer cosas que solamente ellos puedan hacer. Probablemente tenga que ver que los actuales moderadores son gente especialmente activa preguntando y respondiendo.
- la comunidad debería incorporar a nueva gente en las colas de revisión para descargar a los moderadores en esta tarea.
- seguramente se necesitarían más moderadores para gestionar la carga de trabajo que llevan consigo los tres que hay actualmente. Como referencia, [SOru tiene 5 moderadores](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) y [SOpt tiene 7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), mientras que [en SOes solamente hay 3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) para una carga similar.

Comment: De hecho esto afecta [el porcentaje de preguntas/respuestas aceptadas](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-traffic), hay muchas preguntas que deben ser cerradas y somos pocos revisando , estoy de acuerdo con agregar mas moderadores

Comment: @JackNavaRow sí, afecta a muchísimos aspectos: si los moderadores no ven su cola de reportes aligerada por el trabajo de la comunidad, no pueden estar para otras cosas. Si revisamos poco, las preguntas nuevas no reciben suficiente cariño como para formar a usuarios. Si no cerramos rápidamente, se permite responder a muchas cosas que no se debería. Y así un largo etcétera. Así que nada, a revisar todos jeje

Comment: @fedorqui lo que mas afecta siento yo es que hay muchos con la suficiente reputación que no ayudan en la colas de revisión, hay muchos que si queremos ayudar pero no tenemos esa reputación que nos permitiría hacerlo

Comment: @RaulCacacho creo que el límite de 1000 revisiones para obtener el oro da idea del número medio aproximado de revisiones que hará cada persona. Es lógico asumir que un usuario con acceso a ellas hará ese número y luego tal vez alguna más, pero que muchos se quedarán allí. Esto puede parecer malo, pero creo que es más bien bueno, pues así va actualizándose el perfil de personas que revisan y así hay nuevas visiones. Luego prefiero a diez revisando 1000 cosas a uno revisando 10.000, que es lo que pasa ahora. Lo malo es que la gente no tiene suficiente reputación, consecuencia de la graduación.

Comment: Es real. Hay horarios en los que una sugerencia de edición tarda porque son muy pocos y hay mucho por hacer. Brincos diera por ayudar más, pero hasta ahora la reputación en SOes no me da para mucho más. Con todo y eso, se hace y se hace mucho! :) *dime si son latinoooo*

Comment: La comparación estadística entre los sitios es interesante. Quizás nos pareceríamos más a SOpt, pero las colas de cierre y reapertura están disparadas. Me pregunto por qué esas dos en concreto tienen valores tan diferentes al de los otros sitios.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro entiendo que te refieres a que en esos dos colas los moderadores actuáis con mucha más frecuencia que lo que lo hacen los moderadores de SOpt. La de reapertura no la tendría demasiado en cuenta porque es una cola pequeña, pero en la de cierre observo que pesa mucho el hecho de que los tres moderadores seáis también bastante activos en la _recepción_ de usuarios y respuesta de preguntas. De este modo, tareas que la comunidad haría finalmente se ven aceleradas por vuestra acción.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro sería interesante comentar con otros moderadores de SOxx sobre cuál es su filosofía al respecto. En el sitio en el que soy moderador intentamos mantenernos bastante al margen para _empoderar_ a la comunidad, si bien a veces sí mediamos. Básicamente, observo que el trabajo del moderador en este campo es útil a corto plazo, pero a largo plazo es bueno que se abstenga para que la comunidad se fortalezca y tome conciencia de que _debe_ intervenir en las colas para marcar la línea de calidad.

Comment: Y yo que pensaba que pasaba poco tiempo en las colas de revisión... en serio, intento no meterme a no ser que vea que van por cantidades altas... pero parece que aunque pase por ellas, luego vuelven a subir como locas. Tenemos más gente reportando que revisando (lo cual  es bueno y malo respectivamente).

Comment: @fedorqui he estado pensando sobre esto. ¿Podría darse el caso de que los moderadores estemos limpiando esas colas sin darnos cuenta? Me explico: hay veces que voy a las herramientas del moderador y cierro/elimino una pregunta que ha sido reportada, si esa pregunta estaba en la cola de cierre (algo posible), ¿contaría como un moderador actuando en la cola de cierre también? Eso podría explicar que las colas de cierre y de baja calidad tuvieran una mayor representación de los moderadores (pero no valdría para la de reapertura, aunque a veces nos llegan reportes para eso).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro pues no lo sé, la verdad. Si operas desde el menú de moderador, no te computa como revisión desde colas. Ahora bien, no sé cómo extrajeron estos datos. Habría que preguntarlo a Shog9, el que hizo la consulta inicial, o a Nicolas.

Comment: @fedorqui He mirando las estadísticas de los otros sitios y hay una explicación posible: los moderadores de SOes representan un 3-4% de los usuarios que pueden votar en esas colas mientras que en los otros sitios son un porcentaje más bajo (excepto en SOjp) y/o cuentan con una base mucho mayor de usuarios con reputación >3.000 (nosotros tenemos 85, ellos 300-500 cada uno). Por ello, es más probable que haya usuarios activos en las colas en esos sitios, o incluso si lo están al mismo nivel que aquí, la actuación de los moderadores se diluye debido a la cantidad de gente con acceso a ellas.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro siempre pensé que la graduación no debía de ser prioritaria, porque traía consigo un aumento en la reputación necesaria para hacer muchas cosas. Esto que comentamos es una consecuencia. Además, los datos que mostró Mariano en la respuesta que enlazo en mi resuesta muestran que las revisiones dependen de un puñado (casi literal) de usuarios. Hay que ser más activos pidiendo a la gente que actúe, destacar publicaciones al respecto en Meta, esperar que funcione [el consejo sobre revisar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3863/83), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Recordemos que la moderación la realizamos todos los miembros de la comunidad.

Muchas de las tareas de revisión no requieren forzosamente de un [moderador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) para ser completadas pero si de los miembros de la comunidad.

**Como menciona Nicolas, trabajemos en equipo para juntos conseguir mejores resultados.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Invito a todos los miembros de la comunidad que apoyen al sitio realizando regularmente [tareas de revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review).

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review

Answer (score -5):

de mi parte quisiera hacer una observación, me he dado cuenta de muchas muy buenas preguntas, formuladas muy bien y que reciben votos negativos, a mi no me ha pasado y no vengo a quejarme por mi sino que me parece que como en cualquier sitio de internet por acá puede y ojo...pueden haber usuarios que solo se pasan a dar votos negativos, creería eso debe ser manejado de una mejor manera.

Comment: Hola Pablo, gracias por compartir tu observación. La red de StackExchange se toma muy en serio los votos negativos en serie; de hecho, los moderadores recibimos una alerta automática cuando algo así se produce y se han tomado medidas con usuarios que no cumplían las normas y votaban negativamente a otros usuarios sin motivo. Pero eso suelen ser casos aislados y no la norma. Aunque algunos usuarios son más estrictos que otros a la hora de votar de forma positiva/negativa, en general, cuando una pregunta ha recibido varios votos negativos, suele haber algún problema más con la misma.

Comment: ¿Puedes darme algún ejemplo de preguntas con votos negativos injustificados para que las revise?

Comment: que mejor ejemplo que mi mismo comentario, es por eso que muchas veces me han sugerido la pagina en ingles o los foros de msdn, deberían tener más control sobre estas personas que no aportan nada y dejo este comentario como evidencia y/o advertencia para aquellos que empiezan en esta comunidad.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que los votos en meta no funcionan del mismo modo que los del sitio en general. Aquí se utilizan para indicar acuerdo/desacuerdo y no valorando la calidad de la publicación.

Comment: En general esta comunidad es más abierta y positiva (o al menos eso quiero pensar) que el sitio en inglés, donde los usuarios suelen ser menos pacientes con los usuarios nuevos y votan de forma negativa más rápido y sin dejar comentarios. Sí que hay distintos tipos de usuario que aplican un criterio diferente a la hora de votar, pero en no parece que haya un problema de usuarios que se dedican a votar negativo de forma sistemática.

Comment: Hola Pablo, como menciona Alvaro, sería importante agregar ejemplos de preguntas que mencionas, sería importante leer [ask] para que tengas un criterio que permita conocer que esta bien o mal formulado en el sitio, si son varios votos negativos posiblemente no este formulada correctamente la publicación de acuerdo a lo que define el sitio, saludos.

Comment: hola @Elenasys dejo de ejemplo mi comentario (ojalá al borrar mi perfil aún pueda verse) pues me llamo la atencion las primeras dos lineas de la discusión base, a partir de ello creo está de más seguir pidiendo ejemplos, con mi comentario y lo digo para que quede como referencia (y agradezco los votos negativos porque sirven para comprobar mi comentario) para nuevos usuarios o incluso usuarios existentes que pasan por el problema de preguntas validas con votos negativos.