# 2019: La moderación del sitio

Tags: discusión, moderación

Muchas gracias a [@gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) por la traducción.

---

Quisiera compartir con ustedes un informe de estadísticas de moderación para Stack Overflow en español.

Una característica distintiva de los sitios de Stack Exchange es cómo se moderan:

> Diseñamos el motor de red de Stack Exchange para que se autorregulara en su mayor parte, ya que amortizamos el costo general de moderación del sistema en miles de pequeñas porciones de esfuerzo aportadas por usuarios habituales y cotidianos.
> -- [Una teoría de la moderación](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Si bien ciertamente hay [moderadores](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) aquí, una cantidad significativa de la moderación es realizada por personas comunes, utilizando los privilegios que han obtenido en virtud de sus contribuciones al sitio. Cada uno de ustedes aporta un poco de tiempo y esfuerzo, y juntos logran mucho.

Al comenzar un nuevo año, hagamos una pausa y reflexionemos, tomándonos un momento para apreciar el trabajo que hacemos aquí juntos. ¿Y qué podría ser más festivo que una gran cantidad de números? Aquí hay un desglose de las acciones de moderación realizadas en Stack Overflow en español durante los últimos 12 meses:

| Acciones | Moderadores | Comunidad¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Usuarios suspendidos² | 19 | 5 |
| Usuarios destruidos³ | 51 | 0 |
| Usuarios borrados | 6 | 0 |
| Usuarios contactados | 36 | 0 |
| Suspensiones de Usuarios levantadas anticipadamente | 1 | 0 |
| Usuarios suspendidos para revisar | 1 | 0 |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola ediciones sugeridas | 310 | 19359 |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola votos de reapertura | 39 | 1456 |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola publicaciones de baja calidad | 26 | 20371 |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola respuestas tardías | 7 | 3058 |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola primera publicación | 17 | 21186 |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola votos de cierre | 970 | 21946 |
| Etiquetas fusionadas | 35 | 0 |
| Etiqueta sinónimos propuestos | 13 | 4 |
| Etiqueta sinónimos creados | 5 | 0 |
| Etiqueta resaltar conjunto de idiomas | 15 | 0 |
| Revisiones redactadas | 11 | 0 |
| Preguntas desprotegidas | 2 | 0 |
| Preguntas reabiertas | 144 | 57 |
| Preguntas protegidas | 4 | 118 |
| Preguntas migradas | 7 | 4 |
| Preguntas fusionadas | 3 | 0 |
| Preguntas reportadas⁵ | 15 | 9783 |
| Preguntas cerradas | 3390 | 4104 |
| Preguntas con reportes manejados⁵ | 2915 | 6885 |
| Publicaciones desbloqueadas | 1 | 2 |
| Publicaciones recuperadas | 640 | 881 |
| Publicaciones bloqueadas | 1 | 39 |
| Publicaciones eliminadas⁶ | 4340 | 22548 |
| Publicaciones mandadas al principio | 0 | 8616 |
| Escaladas al equipo de CM | 5 | 0 |
| Comentarios recuperados | 90 | 0 |
| Comentarios reportados | 8 | 975 |
| Comentarios borrados⁷ | 3491 | 10534 |
| Comentarios reportes manejados | 884 | 99 |
| Respuestas reportadas | 30 | 9893 |
| Respuestas reportes manejados | 7184 | 2741 |
| Todos los comentarios de una publicación movidas al chat | 67 | 0 |

#### Notas al pie

¹ "Comunidad" Acá se refiera tanto a [los usuarios de Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users) * sin * [diamantes al lado de sus nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), y para el sistema automatizado, también conocido como [usuario # -1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² El sistema suspenderá a los usuarios en tres circunstancias: cuando un usuario se recrea después de haber sido suspendido previamente, cuando un usuario se recrea después de ser destruido por *spam* o abuso, y cuando una suspensión de toda la red está vigente en una cuenta.

³ Un usuario "destruido" se elimina junto con todo lo que había publicado: preguntas, respuestas, comentarios. [Generalmente se usa como una forma conveniente de deshacerse del contenido no deseado.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ Esto cuenta cada revisión que se envió (no se omitió), por lo que las 2 revisiones de ediciones sugeridas necesarias para aprobar una edición contarían como 2, con el objetivo de indicar la frecuencia de las acciones de moderación. Esto también se aplica a reportes, etc.

⁵ Incluye reportes de cierre (pero *no* votos de cierre o reapertura).

⁶ Esto ignora numerosas eliminaciones que suceden automáticamente en respuesta a alguna otra acción.

⁷ Esto incluye los comentarios eliminados por sus propios autores (que también representan cierto número de marcas de comentarios manejados).

#### Otras lecturas

- ¿Quieres ver cómo han cambiado estos números con el tiempo? Publiqué un informe similar aquí el año pasado: [2018: La moderación del sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3850/10)...
- Tambien puedes mirar [El reporte en otros sitios](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- O lee detenidamente [información detallada sobre el número de preguntas cerradas y reabiertas en todos los sitios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)

Les deseamos a todos un feliz año nuevo...

---

(Muchas gracias a [@Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) por todo el trabajo duro con consultas SQL y escribir la [publicación inicial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392550/) para la comunidad.)

Comment: Madre mía, la mitad de las preguntas se cierran con la intervención de un moderador

Comment: @fedorqui la peor son los reportes de preguntas/respuestas y aun hay preguntas malas sin ser reportadas y comparando con las estadisticas del año pasado, los moderadores moderan mas y los usuarios comunidad menos

Comment: @Jack ¿a qué puntos te refieres exactamente? Habría que ver el desglose de esos reportes, pues muchos de ellos van directamente a la cola de moderadores y por tanto no puede gestionarlos la comunidad. Véanse [las estadísticas de SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392550/1983854) por ejemplo.

Comment: @fedor si es asi, se esta abusando en el enlace reportar/se necesita la intervencion de un moderador

Comment: @Jack no es solo ese el reporte que va directamente a los moderadores. Por ejemplo, si alguien marca como "muy baja calidad" y ya ha pasado por la cola, no vuelve a entrar en ella y la gestiona directamente un moderador.