# 2020: La moderación del sitio

Tags: discusión, moderación

Quisiera compartir con ustedes un informe de estadísticas de moderación para Stack Overflow en español.

Una característica distintiva de los sitios de Stack Exchange es cómo se moderan:

> Diseñamos el motor de red de Stack Exchange para que se autorregulara en su mayor parte, ya que amortizamos el costo general de moderación del sistema en miles de pequeñas porciones de esfuerzo aportadas por usuarios habituales y cotidianos.
> -- [Una teoría de la moderación](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Si bien ciertamente hay [moderadores](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) aquí, una cantidad significativa de la moderación es realizada por personas comunes, utilizando los privilegios que han obtenido en virtud de sus contribuciones al sitio. Cada uno de ustedes aporta un poco de tiempo y esfuerzo, y juntos logran mucho.

Al comenzar un nuevo año, hagamos una pausa y reflexionemos, tomándonos un momento para apreciar el trabajo que hacemos aquí juntos. ¿Y qué podría ser más festivo que una gran cantidad de números? Aquí hay un desglose de las acciones de moderación realizadas en Stack Overflow en español durante los últimos 12 meses:

| Acciones | Moderadores | Comunidad¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Usuarios suspendidos² | 6 | 4 |
| Usuarios destruidos³ | 27 | 0 |
| Usuarios borrados | 1 | 0 |
| Usuarios contactados | 11 | 0 |
| Suspensiones de Usuarios levantadas anticipadamente | 1 | 0 |
| Usuarios suspendidos para revisar | 2 | 0 |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola ediciones sugeridas | 216 | 12837 |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola votos de reapertura | 23 | 861 |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola publicaciones de baja calidad | 42 | 17883 |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola respuestas tardías | 6 | 3830 |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola primera publicación | 53 | 24346 |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola votos de cierre | 339 | 14507 |
| Etiquetas fusionadas | 41 | 0 |
| Etiqueta sinónimos propuestos | 34 | 3 |
| Etiqueta sinónimos creados | 39 | 0 |
| Revisiones redactadas | 8 | 0 |
| Preguntas desprotegidas | 3 | 2 |
| Preguntas reabiertas | 87 | 32 |
| Preguntas protegidas | 8 | 120 |
| Preguntas migradas | 3 | 2 |
| Preguntas fusionadas | 1 | 0 |
| Preguntas reportadas⁵ | 14 | 9433 |
| Preguntas cerradas | 2562 | 3387 |
| Preguntas con reportes manejados⁵ | 2232 | 7154 |
| Publicaciones desbloqueadas | 0 | 3 |
| Publicaciones recuperadas | 224 | 1083 |
| Publicaciones bloqueadas | 3 | 28 |
| Publicaciones eliminadas⁶ | 4027 | 23577 |
| Publicaciones mandadas al principio | 0 | 8517 |
| Escaladas al equipo de CM | 2 | 0 |
| Comentarios recuperados | 79 | 0 |
| Comentarios reportados | 2 | 758 |
| Comentarios borrados⁷ | 2875 | 15389 |
| Comentarios reportes manejados | 650 | 110 |
| Respuestas reportadas | 12 | 9568 |
| Respuestas reportes manejados | 7124 | 2450 |
| Todos los comentarios de una publicación movidas al chat | 58 | 0 |

#### Notas al pie

¹ "Comunidad" Acá se refiera tanto a [los usuarios de Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users) * sin * [diamantes al lado de sus nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), y para el sistema automatizado, también conocido como [usuario # -1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² El sistema suspenderá a los usuarios en tres circunstancias: cuando un usuario se recrea después de haber sido suspendido previamente, cuando un usuario se recrea después de ser destruido por *spam* o abuso, y cuando una suspensión de toda la red está vigente en una cuenta.

³ Un usuario "destruido" se elimina junto con todo lo que había publicado: preguntas, respuestas, comentarios. [Generalmente se usa como una forma conveniente de deshacerse del contenido no deseado.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ Esto cuenta cada revisión que se envió (no se omitió), por lo que las 2 revisiones de ediciones sugeridas necesarias para aprobar una edición contarían como 2, con el objetivo de indicar la frecuencia de las acciones de moderación. Esto también se aplica a reportes, etc.

⁵ Incluye reportes de cierre (pero *no* votos de cierre o reapertura).

⁶ Esto ignora numerosas eliminaciones que suceden automáticamente en respuesta a alguna otra acción.

⁷ Esto incluye los comentarios eliminados por sus propios autores (que también representan cierto número de marcas de comentarios manejados).

#### Otras lecturas

- ¿Quieres ver cómo han cambiado estos números con el tiempo? Publiqué un informe similar aquí el año pasado: [2019: La moderación del sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4523/)...
- Tambien puedes mirar [El reporte en otros sitios](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222020%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)

Les deseamos a todos un feliz año nuevo...

---

Muchas gracias a [@Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9) por todo el trabajo duro con consultas SQL.

Comment: Uy, hemos pasado de 21K a 14K revisiones en la cola de cierre hechas por la comunidad. En otras colas hay descensos similares. Como [dije en 2018](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3855/83), el equipo de moderadores carga con demasiado volumen de trabajo.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Si pero parece que hay menos tarea de moderacion? Al menos parece que las cifras están bajando en ambas columnas.

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica probablemente. Hay menos preguntas.

Comment: Tal vez sea más soportable para los moderadores entonces. Hay que pedirles

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica que cuatro moderadores hagan (además de todo lo propio de moderadores) revisiones y eliminen y cierren tantísimas publicaciones seguramente indica que buena parte de esto podría hacerlo la comunidad: tendríamos más consenso y los moderadores podrían centrarse en mirar cosas específicas de su campo. Véase [mi respuesta con comparación entre años](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4999/83).

Answer (score 1):

Comparemos los datos de los tres años en que tenemos:

- [2018: La moderación del sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3850/83)
- [2019: La moderación del sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4523/83)
- [2020: La moderación del sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4990/83)

**M20* y C20* corresponden, respectivamente, a *moderadores el año 2020* y *comunidad el año 2020*. Lo correspondiente con *M19*, *C19*, *M18* y *C18*.

*m%* indica qué porcentaje del total lo hicieron los moderadores.

| Action | M18 | C18 | **m%** | M19 | C19 | **m%** | M20 | C20 | **m%** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Usuarios suspendidos² | 22 | 4 | **85%** | 19 | 5 | **79%** | 6 | 4 | **60%** |
| Usuarios destruidos³ | 54 | 0 | **100%** | 51 | 0 | **100%** | 27 | 0 | **100%** |
| Usuarios borrados | 12 | 0 | **100%** | 6 | 0 | **100%** | 1 | 0 | **100%** |
| Usuarios contactados | 55 | 0 | **100%** | 36 | 0 | **100%** | 11 | 0 | **100%** |
| Suspensiones de Usuarios levantadas anticipadamente | 0 | 0 |  | 1 | 0 | **100%** | 1 | 0 | **100%** |
| User review-bans lifted early | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  | 0 | 0 |  |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola ediciones sugeridas | 828 | 20646 | **4%** | 310 | 19359 | **2%** | 216 | 12837 | **2%** |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola votos de reapertura | 169 | 1452 | **10%** | 39 | 1456 | **3%** | 23 | 861 | **3%** |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola publicaciones de baja calidad | 267 | 15895 | **2%** | 26 | 20371 | **0%** | 42 | 17883 | **0%** |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola respuestas tardías | 16 | 3036 | **1%** | 7 | 3058 | **0%** | 6 | 3830 | **0%** |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola primera publicación | 87 | 21021 | **0%** | 17 | 21186 | **0%** | 53 | 24346 | **0%** |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola votos de cierre | 1917 | 19553 | **9%** | 970 | 21946 | **4%** | 339 | 14507 | **2%** |
| Etiquetas fusionadas | 4 | 0 | **100%** | 35 | 0 | **100%** | 41 | 0 | **100%** |
| Etiqueta sinónimos propuestos | 15 | 11 | **58%** | 13 | 4 | **76%** | 34 | 3 | **92%** |
| Etiqueta sinónimos creados | 27 | 0 | **100%** | 5 | 0 | **100%** | 39 | 0 | **100%** |
| Revisiones redactadas | 0 | 0 |  | 11 | 0 | **100%** | 8 | 0 | **100%** |
| Preguntas desprotegidas | 2 | 0 | **100%** | 2 | 0 | **100%** | 3 | 2 | **60%** |
| Preguntas reabiertas | 230 | 62 | **79%** | 144 | 57 | **72%** | 87 | 32 | **73%** |
| Preguntas protegidas | 3 | 83 | **3%** | 4 | 118 | **3%** | 8 | 120 | **6%** |
| Preguntas migradas | 11 | 1 | **92%** | 7 | 4 | **64%** | 3 | 2 | **60%** |
| Preguntas fusionadas | 0 | 0 |  | 3 | 0 | **100%** | 1 | 0 | **100%** |
| Preguntas reportadas⁵ | 42 | 9500 | **0%** | 15 | 9783 | **0%** | 14 | 9433 | **0%** |
| Preguntas cerradas | 4875 | 3383 | **59%** | 3390 | 4104 | **45%** | 2562 | 3387 | **43%** |
| Preguntas con reportes manejados⁵ | 3434 | 6108 | **36%** | 2915 | 6885 | **30%** | 2232 | 7154 | **24%** |
| Publicaciones desbloqueadas | 5 | 1 | **83%** | 1 | 2 | **33%** | 0 | 3 | **0%** |
| Publicaciones recuperadas | 842 | 875 | **49%** | 640 | 881 | **42%** | 224 | 1083 | **17%** |
| Publicaciones bloqueadas | 7 | 33 | **18%** | 1 | 39 | **3%** | 3 | 28 | **10%** |
| Publicaciones eliminadas⁶ | 5464 | 19805 | **22%** | 4340 | 22548 | **16%** | 4027 | 23577 | **15%** |
| Publicaciones mandadas al principio | 0 | 8711 | **0%** | 0 | 8616 | **0%** | 0 | 8517 | **0%** |
| Escaladas al equipo de CM | 7 | 0 | **100%** | 5 | 0 | **100%** | 2 | 0 | **100%** |
| Comentarios recuperados | 203 | 0 | **100%** | 90 | 0 | **100%** | 79 | 0 | **100%** |
| Comentarios reportados | 7 | 804 | **1%** | 8 | 975 | **1%** | 2 | 758 | **0%** |
| Comentarios borrados⁷ | 5168 | 11047 | **32%** | 3491 | 10534 | **25%** | 2875 | 15389 | **16%** |
| Comentarios reportes manejados | 753 | 58 | **93%** | 884 | 99 | **90%** | 650 | 110 | **86%** |
| Respuestas reportadas | 52 | 8503 | **1%** | 30 | 9893 | **0%** | 12 | 9568 | **0%** |
| Respuestas reportes manejados | 6392 | 2163 | **75%** | 7184 | 2741 | **72%** | 7124 | 2450 | **74%** |
| Todos los comentarios de una publicación movidas al chat | 97 | 0 | **100%** | 67 | 0 | **100%** | 58 | 0 | **100%** |

Y veamos también sumas totales y evoluciones entre años:

| Acción | s18 | s19 | s20 | %18-19 | %18-20 | %19-20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Usuarios suspendidos² | 26 | 24 | 10 | **92%** | **38%** | **42%** |
| Usuarios destruidos³ | 54 | 51 | 27 | **94%** | **50%** | **53%** |
| Usuarios borrados | 12 | 6 | 1 | **50%** | **8%** | **17%** |
| Usuarios contactados | 55 | 36 | 11 | **65%** | **20%** | **31%** |
| Suspensiones de Usuarios levantadas anticipadamente | 0 | 1 | 1 |  |  | **100%** |
| User review-bans lifted early | 0 | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola ediciones sugeridas | 21474 | 19669 | 13053 | **92%** | **61%** | **66%** |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola votos de reapertura | 1621 | 1495 | 884 | **92%** | **55%** | **59%** |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola publicaciones de baja calidad | 16162 | 20397 | 17925 | **126%** | **111%** | **88%** |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola respuestas tardías | 3052 | 3065 | 3836 | **100%** | **126%** | **125%** |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola primera publicación | 21108 | 21203 | 24399 | **100%** | **116%** | **115%** |
| Tarea de revisión⁴: Cola votos de cierre | 21470 | 22916 | 14846 | **107%** | **69%** | **65%** |
| Etiquetas fusionadas | 4 | 35 | 41 | **875%** | **1025%** | **117%** |
| Etiqueta sinónimos propuestos | 26 | 17 | 37 | **65%** | **142%** | **218%** |
| Etiqueta sinónimos creados | 27 | 5 | 39 | **19%** | **144%** | **780%** |
| Revisiones redactadas | 0 | 11 | 8 |  |  | **73%** |
| Preguntas desprotegidas | 2 | 2 | 5 | **100%** | **250%** | **250%** |
| Preguntas reabiertas | 292 | 201 | 119 | **69%** | **41%** | **59%** |
| Preguntas protegidas | 86 | 122 | 128 | **142%** | **149%** | **105%** |
| Preguntas migradas | 12 | 11 | 5 | **92%** | **42%** | **45%** |
| Preguntas fusionadas | 0 | 3 | 1 |  |  | **33%** |
| Preguntas reportadas⁵ | 9542 | 9798 | 9447 | **103%** | **99%** | **96%** |
| Preguntas cerradas | 8258 | 7494 | 5949 | **91%** | **72%** | **79%** |
| Preguntas con reportes manejados⁵ | 9542 | 9800 | 9386 | **103%** | **98%** | **96%** |
| Publicaciones desbloqueadas | 6 | 3 | 3 | **50%** | **50%** | **100%** |
| Publicaciones recuperadas | 1717 | 1521 | 1307 | **89%** | **76%** | **86%** |
| Publicaciones bloqueadas | 40 | 40 | 31 | **100%** | **78%** | **78%** |
| Publicaciones eliminadas⁶ | 25269 | 26888 | 27604 | **106%** | **109%** | **103%** |
| Publicaciones mandadas al principio | 8711 | 8616 | 8517 | **99%** | **98%** | **99%** |
| Escaladas al equipo de CM | 7 | 5 | 2 | **71%** | **29%** | **40%** |
| Comentarios recuperados | 203 | 90 | 79 | **44%** | **39%** | **88%** |
| Comentarios reportados | 811 | 983 | 760 | **121%** | **94%** | **77%** |
| Comentarios borrados⁷ | 16215 | 14025 | 18264 | **86%** | **113%** | **130%** |
| Comentarios reportes manejados | 811 | 983 | 760 | **121%** | **94%** | **77%** |
| Respuestas reportadas | 8555 | 9923 | 9580 | **116%** | **112%** | **97%** |
| Respuestas reportes manejados | 8555 | 9925 | 9574 | **116%** | **112%** | **96%** |
| Todos los comentarios de una publicación movidas al chat | 97 | 67 | 58 | **69%** | **60%** | **87%** |

Comment: las traducciones son un chusco, cogí las que hay en las preguntas enlazadas.

Comment: Gracias por publicar los datos tan detallados. Los números de la cola de primera publicación parecen un poco raros.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro veo que tanto Primera publicación como Respuestas tardías crecieron, mientras que las otras no. Son precisamente a las que se accede con una reputación menor ([500 puntos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)), mientras que por ejemplo cierre y reapertura es con más ([3000 puntos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)). ¿Será que se ha acumulado más nuevo revisor y que los antiguos con más accesos están dejándolo?