# 2021: La moderación del sitio

Tags: discusión, moderación

Al despedir el año viejo y dar la bienvenida al nuevo, tenemos [la tradición de compartir las estadísticas de moderación del año natural anterior](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion)

Como la mayoría de los presentes sabeis, los sitios de la red de Stack Exchange se moderan de forma algo diferente a otros sitios de la web:

> Hemos diseñado el motor de la red de Stack Exchange para que se autorregule en su mayor parte, en el sentido de que amortizamos el coste global de moderación del sistema entre miles de minúsculas porciones de esfuerzo aportadas por los usuarios regulares y cotidianos.
> -- [Una teoría de la moderación](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Esto no elimina la necesidad de tener [moderadores](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) por completo, pero significa que la mayor parte del trabajo de moderación es llevado a cabo por gente normal. Cada poco del tiempo y esfuerzo que aportáis al sitio os da acceso a más privilegios que podéis utilizar para ayudar en este esfuerzo, todo lo cual produce un efecto acumulativo que marca una gran diferencia.

Así que, al despedirnos del año 2021, echemos la vista atrás para ver lo que hemos conseguido como comunidad... echando un vistazo a algunas [*excitantes* estadísticas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZntT.gif). A continuación se muestra un desglose de las acciones de moderación realizadas en Stack Overflow en Español durante los últimos 12 meses:

| Acción | Moderadores | Comunidad¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Usuarios suspendidos² | 59 | 6 |
| Usuarios destruidos³ | 40 | 0 |
| Usuarios borrados | 7 | 0 |
| Usuarios contactados | 80 | 0 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Ediciones Sugeridas | 109 | 10975 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Votos de Reapertura | 13 | 1457 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Publicaciones de Baja Calidad | 39 | 20829 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Respuestas Tardías | 8 | 3759 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Primeras Preguntas | 0 | 7194 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Primeras Publicaciones | 14 | 15313 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Primeras Respuestas | 0 | 2489 |
| Tareas de revisión⁴: cola Votos de Cierre | 133 | 10897 |
| Etiquetas unidas | 3 | 0 |
| Sinónimos de Etiqueta propuestos | 3 | 3 |
| Sinónimos de Etiqueta creados | 3 | 0 |
| Revisiones redactadas | 4 | 0 |
| Preguntas reabiertas | 40 | 117 |
| Preguntas Protegidas | 1 | 99 |
| Preguntas Migradas | 2 | 0 |
| Preguntas Reportadas⁵ | 10 | 10588 |
| Preguntas Cerradas | 2230 | 5655 |
| Reportes en preguntas gestionados⁵ | 1935 | 8663 |
| Publicaciones Desbloqueadas | 0 | 1 |
| Publicaciones Recuperadas | 144 | 760 |
| Publicaciones bloqueadas | 1 | 39 |
| Publicaciones eliminadas⁶ | 3129 | 27257 |
| Publicaciones promocionadas | 0 | 8206 |
| Escaladas al equipo de Community Managers | 5 | 0 |
| Comentarios recuperados | 52 | 0 |
| Comentarios reportados | 0 | 950 |
| Comentarios eliminados⁷ | 2347 | 11306 |
| Reportes de comentario gestionados | 796 | 156 |
| Respuestas reportadas | 2 | 8687 |
| Reportes de Respuesta gestionados | 5856 | 2743 |
| Todos los comentarios en una publicación movidos a un chat | 49 | 0 |

#### Notas a pie de página

¹ "Comunidad" aquí se refiere tanto a [los miembros de Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users) *sin* [diamantes junto a sus nombres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), como a los sistemas automatizados conocidos como [usuario #-1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² El sistema suspenderá a los usuarios en tres circunstancias: cuando un usuario es recreado después de haber sido suspendido previamente, cuando un usuario es recreado después de haber sido destruido por spam o abuso, y cuando una suspensión en toda la red está en efecto en una cuenta.

Un usuario "destruido" es eliminado junto con todo lo que había publicado: preguntas, respuestas, comentarios. (Generalmente se utiliza como una forma expeditiva de deshacerse del spam) ([What is the difference between a deleted user and a "destroyed" user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user))

⁴ Esto cuenta cada revisión que fue enviada (no saltada) - así que las 2 revisiones de ediciones sugeridas necesarias para aprobar una edición contarían como 2, el objetivo es indicar la frecuencia de las acciones de moderación. Esto también se aplica a los reportes, etc.

⁵ Incluye cerrar reportes (pero *no* cerrar o reabrir votaciones).

⁶ Esto ignora las numerosas eliminaciones que ocurren automáticamente en respuesta a alguna otra acción.

⁷ Esto incluye los comentarios borrados por sus propios autores (que también suponen un cierto número de reportes de comentarios gestionados).

#### Más lecturas:

- ¿Quieres ver cómo han cambiado estas cifras con el tiempo? Publicamos un informe similar aquí el año pasado: [2020: La moderación del sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4990/13)
- También puede consultar [este informe sobre otros sitios](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222021%3A+un+a%C3%B1o+en+moderaci%C3%B3n%22)
- O consultar [información detallada sobre el número de preguntas cerradas y reabiertas en todos los sitios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374784/208518)

¡Os deseo a todos un feliz 2022! ^_^

---

As we say goodbye to the old year and welcome the new one, we have [a tradition of sharing moderation stats for the preceding calendar year](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22year+in+moderation%22+is%3Aquestion).

As most of you here are aware, sites on the Stack Exchange network are moderated somewhat differently to other sites on the web:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

That doesn't eliminate the need for having [moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) altogether, but it does mean that the bulk of moderation work is carried out by regular folks. Every bit of time and effort y'all contribute to the site gives you access to more privileges you can use to help in this effort, all of which produce a cumulative effect that makes a big difference.

So as we say goodbye to 2021, let us look back at what we accomplished as a community... by looking at some [*exciting* stats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZntT.gif). Below is a breakdown of moderation actions performed on Stack Overflow en español over the past 12 months:

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 59 | 6 |
| Users destroyed³ | 40 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 7 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 80 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 109 | 10975 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 13 | 1457 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 39 | 20829 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 8 | 3759 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First questions queue | 0 | 7194 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 14 | 15313 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First answers queue | 0 | 2489 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 133 | 10897 |
| Tags merged | 3 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 3 | 3 |
| Tag synonyms created | 3 | 0 |
| Revisions redacted | 4 | 0 |
| Questions reopened | 40 | 117 |
| Questions protected | 1 | 99 |
| Questions migrated | 2 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 10 | 10588 |
| Questions closed | 2230 | 5655 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 1935 | 8663 |
| Posts unlocked | 0 | 1 |
| Posts undeleted | 144 | 760 |
| Posts locked | 1 | 39 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 3129 | 27257 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 8206 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 5 | 0 |
| Comments undeleted | 52 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 0 | 950 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 2347 | 11306 |
| Comment flags handled | 796 | 156 |
| Answers flagged | 2 | 8687 |
| Answer flags handled | 5856 | 2743 |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 49 | 0 |

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ A "destroyed" user is deleted along with all that they had posted: questions, answers, comments. [Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 2 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 2, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁵ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁶ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁷ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

#### Further reading:

- Wanna see how these numbers have changed over time? We posted a similar report here last year: [2020: La moderación del sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4990/13)
- You can also check out [this report on other sites](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222021%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)
- Or peruse [detailed information on the number of questions closed and reopened across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374784/208518)

Wishing everyone a happy 2022! ^_^

Comment: esto es global o del sitio en español???

Comment: Del sitio en español