# ¿Por qué este año no se han publicado las estadísticas de moderación del año 2022?

Tags: soporte, estado-completado

Ya estamos en febrero y aún no se han publicado las estadísticas de moderación del año 2022. ¿Sucede algo que no sepamos de por qué no se han publicado estas estadísticas, o es que ya no se van a publicar más?

**Ejemplo de las estadísticas del año 2021:** [2021: La moderación del sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5348/2021-la-moderaci%c3%b3n-del-sitio)

Comment: Buena pregunta!!!! voy a preguntar....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JNat estuvo mirando este tema, y es un script automático (o al menos lo tienen así) el que postea esta información. Por algún motivo, este año no funciono.

Los CM ya tomaron el tema, y en los próximos días tendremos las estadísticas como corresponde.

Gracias por darte cuenta!