# El enlace del anuncio "Tengo una duda sobre cómo funciona el sitio" no apunta a la respuesta correspondiente

Tags: bug, anuncios-de-ayuda

Hace unas semanas se empezaron a mostrar "anuncios de ayuda a usuarios" en el panel lateral de la página de inicio del sitio. El anuncio en cuestión apunta a la respuesta 3762 en lugar de la respuesta 3764 de

[Consejos sobre cómo usar el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3761/)

La 3762 es "Marcar la respuesta como aceptada te da +2 en la reputación"

Comment: sí, ya se informó a Nicolas en el chat. Todos apuntan a la misma respuesta.

Comment: @fedorqui ¿Te refieres a [este post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49008261#49008261) tuyo?

Comment: [Incluso antes](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48778564#48778564). Hace un par de días [Nicolas dijo que está en ello](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49041661#49041661)

Comment: @fedorqui Gracias.

Comment: Pasa lo mismo con el Banner "Colabora con el sitio revisando lo que los otros escribieron" de @fedorqui. Apunta también a la [3762](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3761/consejos-sobre-c%C3%B3mo-usar-el-sitio/3762#3762)

Comment: Gracias @OscarR. fedorqui comentó que pasa con todos los banners de ayuda

Comment: parece que ahora sí está funcionando correctamente.