# Falta una tilde en "Descubre cómo funciona" en algunos de los anuncios de "Consejos sobre cómo usar el sitio"

Tags: bug, anuncios-de-ayuda

Los [Consejos sobre cómo usar el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3761/83) tienen unos anuncios que ya se muestran aleatoriamente cuando visitas el sitio.

Veo que a veces le falta una tilde al texto que hay debajo de todos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Descubre aquí **<s>como</s>** hacerlo.

Si bien otros sí que están bien (con otro verbo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Descubre aquí **cómo** funciona.

En todos los casos debería ser con tilde, pues se trata de un adverbio interrogativo indirecto ([*cómo*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=NRljHeeb2D6KmUqa9B) en el DPD).

Comment: @Konamiman no son textos traducidos sino originales

Comment: Mil perdones. ¿Tenemos alguna etiqueta para casos de correcciones como éstas?

Comment: @Konamiman mmmm realmente no. Se lo comentamos al CM Nicolas en [The Terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal) y esperamos a que se resuelva. Cuando no está en Transifex, es un poco como hace un par de años cuando estabas tú: esperar a que algún empleado tenga tiempo y lo revise :D

Comment: Ok, pues si @JuanM me da acceso lo corrijo en un minuto, total ya sé cómo funciona todo X-D

Comment: @Konamiman no no, es que ha cambiado bastante todo. Esto son imágenes y por tanto hay que pedir al departamento correspondiente que las vuelvan a crear. En cuanto a las cadenas de Transifex, g3rv4 hizo un sistema para que las vayamos traduciendo nosotros, con validación posterior y pull de un CM. Está descrito en [Traduciendo el sitio… Esta vez, con más control sobre el proceso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3378/83)

Comment: Dicho lo cual, qué bueno verte por aquí de nuevo! Hubo que viajar al 1999 para que volvieras :P Ahora quédate :)

Comment: Lo que realmente me gustaría es volver a 2016 y congelar el tiempo para siempre... pero sí, ya iba siendo hora de dar alguna señal de vida.