# Recordemos a la gente que es bueno aceptar respuestas

Tags: discusión, respuesta-aceptada

Estaba hoy mirando unas preguntas cuando vi que en una de ellas el autor daba las gracias a una respuesta. Daba las gracias y ya está, pues ni aceptaba la pregunta ni la votaba.

Después revisando el perfil del usuario me di cuenta que nunca ha aceptado una respuesta ni siquiera ha votado en toda su historia, pese a tener decenas de preguntas.

Inmediatamente dejé el mensaje de rigor:

> Si la respuesta solucionó tu problema, es buena práctica aceptar la respuesta. Más info en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Pero me pregunté: ¿estará pasando con frecuencia que un usuario con distintas preguntas con respuestas válidas no ha aceptado ninguna? ¿No sería interesante detectar a esta gente para explicarles o recordarles de forma cordial que aceptar es una gran manera de dar gracias a las personas que respondieron, ayudando a hacer destacar ese pedazo de conocimiento?

¿Alguien se animaría a crear una consulta en [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) para detectar eso, usuarios con 10+ preguntas sin ninguna respuesta aceptada?

<sub><sup>1</sup> Por si a alguien le interesa, el código del comentario es:</sub>

```
Si la respuesta solucionó tu problema, es buena práctica aceptar la respuesta. Más info en [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
```

Comment: Vale la pena mencionar que entre los esfuerzos para  hacer este recordatorio está un lindo banner que apunta a https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/65. Sería interesante saber cuanta gente hace clic a ese banner.

Comment: @Rubén supongo que bastante, pero no llega a quien más lo necesita :) De ahí que sería útil ir caso a caso en los más flagrantes porque a veces resulta que es que no se habían dado cuenta.

Comment: Porque resulta que Meta lo ve cierta gente, pero en algunos casos no es la gente a la que querríamos llegar. Por ejemplo la medalla [Vox Pópuli](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/71/vox-populi) se otorgó a apenas 8 personas en los 30 días que estuvo destacado [¿Ya conseguiste tu medalla Vox Populi?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4188/83), mientras que obtuvo 43 votos.

Comment: Por lo que he visto, los usuarios que no aceptan las respuestas por lo general son nuevos o no muy conocedores de las practicas de la pagina, si se comenta `"es buena práctica aceptar la respuesta"`, puede que no entiendan el concepto de **"aceptar"**, por tanto habría que ser mas específicos y colocar algo como `"marcar el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la pregunta"` o algo parecido.

Comment: @fedorqui, fijate si esto sirve: https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1094158/usuarios-con-10-o-mas-preguntas-sin-aceptar

Comment: Por otro lado, creo que no estaba bien visto pedir que se acepten nuestras propias respuestas, a mi, de hecho me cae mal hacerlo. Entiendo que estás hablando de algo más general, una campaña o un mailing general?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Una versión un poco más rebuscada es pedirle al AP que lea [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) . Para los "pragmáticos" quizás resulte poco atractiva pues el "resultado al final del día es el mismo", pero para los "académicos" quizás resulte mas apropiada.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en lo que dices, a mi en lo personal sigue sin gustarme,  pero es un "issue" mío ;-)

Comment: @fedorqui, estoy mirando la consulta que te pasé, es algo más amplia de lo que pedías, ya que muestra todos los usuarios que tienen más de 10 preguntas sin aceptar. Sorprende la gente con reputación e historia y con tantas preguntas sin aceptar. Para refinarla, habría que ver los usuarios con 0 preguntas aceptadas y más de 10 sin aceptar

Comment: Esto si: https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/edit/1094182

Comment: coincido con @PatricioMoracho en que no esta bueno pedirlo.. peroooo.. dada la poca cantidad de reputacion que acumulan muchos usuarios, y "aprovechando" que soy moderador, los pido para todos lados, cada vez que encuentro una respuesta sin aceptar. Y tambien me pasa lo contrario, que tengo que pedir que no acepten cosas porque si.. Pero me estoy quedando corto de ideas con el tema campañas, y hay un mal general sobre toda la red respecto a esto y otras cosas.

Comment: ¡Genial @Patricio! Le hice algún cambio para poder jugar con el número de preguntas y que salga también un enlace al perfil del usuario. Además, añadí la fecha del último acceso pues en muchos casos es bastante lejana. https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1094273/usuarios-con-10-o-mas-preguntas-todas-sin-aceptar Mil gracias por la consulta.

Comment: Coincido con todo lo hablado por los comentarios. Por mi parte siempre que me encuentro con algun caso como lo mencionado en la publicación miro de dejar un comentario amigable indicando al OP que **debe aceptar la respuesta que MÁS le haya servido** (en mi caso lo hago para todo tipo de respuestas, tanto las mias como las de otros users siempre que lo vea). Estaria bien mirar de fomentar esta buena práctica.

Comment: Interesante: ya uno de los usuarios que salían en la consulta de @Patricio aceptó su primera respuesta tras explicárselo en los comentarios. Vamos bien :)

Comment: @fedorqui, te lo has tomado en serio! estuve viendo algunos casos y veo tu "huellas" en todos lados, enhorabuena! ojalá de buenos resultados, comenzaré aplicar tu comentario.

Comment: Pasados unos días, el resultado ha sido poco esperanzador: apenas un usuario aceptó una respuesta, tras escribir a una decena.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

De acuerdo con lo dicho en los comentarios por diferente gente, el texto a dejar al usuario podría ser del tipo:

> ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, @usuario? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Comment: (lo pongo como wiki para que se pueda perfilar entre todos)

Comment: faltaria algo para incentivar, propongo, si aceptas la respuesta [ganaras 2 puntos de reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) y accederas a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: por otro lado,opino que es mejor quitar *Dado que eres nuevo* asi sirve también para usuarios antiguos  que tienen mal habito o no saben como funcionamos; dejo el comentario para ver si esta de acuerdo la comunidad

Comment: @JackNavaRow gracias por las mejoras! Lo de _nuevos privilegios_ no acabo de verlo. Raro sería que con un +2 se consiga cambiar de bloque de privilegios.

Comment: eso se llama marketing, es como cuando vez una publicidad de 5.999 ;); ahora eres libre de cambiarlo

Comment: @JackNavaRow jajaja bueno

Comment: podemos cambiarlo, a podrias acceder a nuevos privilegios

Comment: @Jack ¡buena idea! Edité para ponerlo así

Comment: Concuerdo con @JackNavaRow, deberíamos quitar el "Dado que eres nuevo". Así, el comentario se aplica globalmente y no se amarra a un nivel de rep o fecha de ingreso.

Comment: @JheymanMejia lo puse como wiki para que se pueda perfilar entre todos. Dale.

Comment: Estrenando el comentario: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/288679/288819?noredirect=1#comment530863_288819

Comment: @JheymanMejia qué éxito, ¡funcionó! El AP ya había aceptado otra hace tiempo, pero igualmente genial que con el comentario se le recordara.

Comment: ahoraes mi turno estrenar [el comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/149951/relacion-muchos-a-muchos-en-laravel#comment532924_150787) que bien se ve!! grande nuestro mod fedorqui

Comment: Acabo de hacer una edición a la respuesta, pueden revertirla o editarla si les parece.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Alguien se animaría a crear una consulta en [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) para detectar eso, usuarios con 10+ preguntas sin ninguna respuesta aceptada?

No soy (ni quiero ser) experto en bases de datos, pero alguien podría tomar esto como punto de partida:

```sql
WITH no_votos AS
(
  SELECT
    Id, DisplayName
  FROM
    Users
  WHERE
    UpVotes + DownVotes = 0
),
preguntas_por_usuario AS
(
  SELECT
    OwnerUserId, COUNT(*) Posts
  FROM
    Posts
  WHERE
    PostTypeId = 1 AND
    AcceptedAnswerId IS NULL
  GROUP BY
    OwnerUserId
)
SELECT
  no_votos.Id, DisplayName, Posts
FROM
  no_votos
RIGHT JOIN
  preguntas_por_usuario ON no_votos.Id = preguntas_por_usuario.OwnerUserId
WHERE
  Id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  Posts DESC
```

Seleccionamos todos los usuarios que no han votado nunca (consulta `no_votos`) y las preguntas (`PostTypeId` con valor 1) que no tengan respuesta aceptada (`AcceptedAnswerId` es nulo) agrupadas por usuario (consulta `preguntas_por_usuario`).

Al juntar ambas tablas mediante identificador de usuario deberíamos tener a los usuarios que no han votado nunca pero han hecho preguntas. No se si la consulta es correcta, me arroja como campeón de Stack Overflow en Español al [usuario 24558](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/24558) con 61 preguntas sin votar/aceptar de un total de 71 preguntas en su haber.

Comment: Uoooo gracias! Nótese que lo mismo quedó oculto entre tanto comentario, pero [Patricio dio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4288/recordemos-a-la-gente-que-es-bueno-aceptar-respuestas/4442#comment16778_4288) una primera versión --> https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/edit/1094182 yo luego pulí un poco en https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1094273/usuarios-con-10-o-mas-preguntas-todas-sin-aceptar

Comment: Debí dejar las consultas a los expertos, mi aproximación se ve torpe e incompleta en comparación.

Comment: Tu idea de mirar gente que ha aceptado _poco_ es muy buena. La he incorporado a la consulta SEDE que _forkeé_ de Patricio y he creado [Usuarios que preguntan mucho y aceptan poco](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1094273/usuarios-que-preguntan-mucho-y-aceptan-poco), con opción de definir mínimo y máximo de respuestas aceptadas.

Comment: La idea de buscar a gente que acepta *poco* no es mía, es lo que pediste al principio O_o

Comment: Pero la consulta que hicimos en SEDE buscaba _nada_ != _poco_.

Answer (score 0):

En [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) con la consulta [Usuarios que preguntan mucho y aceptan poco](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1094273/usuarios-que-preguntan-mucho-y-aceptan-poco) se puede buscar qué usuarios han aceptado poco. Permite definir mínimo y máximo número de preguntas sin respuesta aceptada.

Está basado en [las contribuciones de Patricio Moracho](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4288/recordemos-a-la-gente-que-es-bueno-aceptar-respuestas#comment16778_4288).

Úsese con cautela, no hay que perseguir a nadie sino fijarnos si hay usuarios que desconocen el mecanismo.