# Exámenes, ejercicios y estudiantes caraduras

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Llevo ya unos años en el sitio, no es raro que de vez en cuando salga alguna pregunta con el título

> **AYUDA CON MI EXAMEN POR FAVOR**

Siempre le doy a reportar pero echo en falta una opción que sea *Examen,pregunta de examen o ejercicio sin desarrollar* ya que podría ser de ayuda porque esas preguntas suelen acabar cerradas.

Por otro lado me gustaría proponer, que al igual que se hizo una campaña con la aceptación de respuestas, una a los estudiantes con un enlace a lugares de interés, que por desgracia no nos enseñan en la escuela y descubrimos más tarde.

También un mensaje mas visible sobre que los que estamos en el sitio, no es para hacerles los deberes, si no, que todos somos una comunidad que nos apoyamos los unos a los otros.

Todo esto viene a que hace poco me he encontrado con esto:

- [ayuden es mi examen tengo hasta las 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/368508/ayuden-es-mi-examen-tengo-hasta-las-2)
- [Taller de Mecanica](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/368509/taller-de-mecanica)
- [Ayúdenme por favor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/368513/ay%c3%badenme-por-favor)

Tres preguntas de un mismo examen, esto para mí significa que los estudiantes nos tienen mas como solucionadores de problemas que una comunidad de consultas.

**EDICIÓN**

Las propuestas son:

> - Añadir opción de reporte ***Examen,pregunta de examen o ejercicio sin desarrollar***.
> - Campaña / Banner con link a recorrido, curiosidades, elementos útiles de SOEs
> - Un mensaje más visible sobre quienes somos, qué hacemos y que no hacemos.

Comment: Veo muchas propuestas interesantes: nuevo motivo de cierre por "deberes", campaña para estudiantes (no me queda clara la propuesta en sí) y recordar a los usuarios que no hay que hacer deberes.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' no se si llegaste a ver un banner con gbianci de fondo diciendo *Aceptemos las respuestas correctas* pues algo similar pero con algo como *Soy estudiante y tengo un examen Auxilio!!* o cualquier otra cosa que se relacione, no soy muy bueno en sloganes

Comment: Ah sí, los [Consejos sobre cómo usar el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3761/83) (también hay uno mío). Dado que esos anuncios salen aleatoriamente, puede ser mejor apostar por algo más determinístico: [Advertencias en preguntas potencialmente problemáticas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3299/83) ante títulos que indiquen por dónde van los tiros (por ejemplo si titulas [Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Ayuda%20ayuda%20ayuda)) no te deja). Y luego, pedir a la gente que además de votar negativamente, vote para cerrar

Comment: Claro, se que existen estos sitios, pero por un extraño motivo están en segundo plano, como los magic links, mas de una vez me ha costado encontralos, por ello un lugar con todos los lugares de interes reunidos

Comment: Veo que la pregunta está ganando muchos votos. Para que tenga recorrido y sirva para modificar cosas, sería bueno definir muy bien las propuestas y pasos para implementarlas

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Podemos abrir un chat para no llenar de comentarios esto y realizar una especificación de los puntos

Comment: A partir de esta publicación planteo [Prohibamos la palabra “ayuda” en los títulos de las preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4759/83). Gracias por sacar el tema a debate

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Preguntas de "¡Hacedme el ejercicio que me han mandado!"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/588/preguntas-de-hacedme-el-ejercicio-que-me-han-mandado)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Veo que somos legión, utilicemos nuestro número y declaremos la guerra a estas preguntas

Answer (score 18):

Los foros en inglés de stackexchange.com son feroces e implacables. Si haces la pregunta incorrecta, te despluman vivo. Pero, por otra parte, ahi encuentras respuestas a problemas tecnicos dificiles; sus usuarios son profesionales con años de experiencia.

Aqui abundan los estudiantes de todo tipo: los flojonazos y los esforzados. Unos que quieren aprender y otros que quieren que les hagan las tareas.

Dada la escasez de material educativo en castellano, es comprensible que los estudiantes acudan acá con consultas. No creo que se pueda hacer mucho por elevar el nivel de las preguntas. Para progresar en esta profesión tienes que saber inglés; y una vez que te manejas, vas directo a la versión inglesa.

Creo que es un deber social ayudar a los que se esfuerzan legitimamente, por más que sus preguntas sean elementales, pues todos empezamos iguales y aprendimos de otros mejores que nosotros.

A los flojonazos les daría con la puerta en las narices, y también a los desubicados con proyectos grandiosos que no saben ni escribir dos líneas de código. Son personas que no tienen salvación posible.

Comment: Tienes razón en que aquí, el número de profesionales es menor, pero creo que no me expliqué bien en que la queja es sobre los estudiantes que no han desarrollado nada su ejercicio, por ello el titulo del post, no es ningún problema el responder a preguntas sencillas(fibonnacci, elementos de css, etc.), siempre que pongan que han intentado, pero los que ponen su ejercicio sin desarrollar son el problema, ya que puede que no conozcan el funcionamiento y por ello mis proposiciones

Comment: @NicolasOñate. Totalmente de acuerdo. Hay que apoyar al que se esfuerza, al que pone de su parte.

Comment: Si antes odiaba a la comunidad inglesa, ahora la quiero muerta (en comparación).