# Palabras en títulos que pueden derivar en preguntas de baja calidad

Tags: discusión, advertencias-en-preguntas, filtros-de-calidad

Debido a las publicaciones en Meta relacionadas con preguntas de baja calidad, como:

1. [Prohibamos la palabra "ayuda" en los títulos de las preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4759/prohibamos-la-palabra-ayuda-en-los-t%c3%adtulos-de-las-preguntas)
2. [Exámenes, ejercicios y estudiantes caraduras](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4745/ex%c3%a1menes-ejercicios-y-estudiantes-caraduras)
3. [Preguntas de "¡Hacedme el ejercicio que me han mandado!"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/588/preguntas-de-hacedme-el-ejercicio-que-me-han-mandado)
4. [¿Sería posible añadir al artículo "¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?" indicaciones sobre no añadir imágenes con errores, sino texto?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/modificaci%c3%b3n-de-la-p%c3%a1gina-c%c3%b3mo-elaboro-una-buena-pregunta/4433#4433)

Es un tema que ha salido más de una vez, con diferentes propuestas y llevando a la última, [pidiendo la prohibición de la palabra **ayuda** de los títulos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4759/83).

En los comentarios de [Prohibamos la palabra ayuda en los títulos de las preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4759/prohibamos-la-palabra-ayuda-en-los-t%C3%ADtulos-de-las-preguntas?cb=1) han surgido más palabras derivadas que se cree que deben prohibirse o mostrar una advertencia. **El fin de esta publicación es ir recogiéndolas para en caso de que el conflicto persista tener un punto de referencia con todas las posibles palabras conflictivas**.

Por ahora las que tenemos en el punto de mira son:

> - **Ayuda**: Implantado.
> - **Examen**: Sin calificar.
> - **Ejercicio**: Sin calificar.
> - **Necesito**: Sin calificar.
> - **Por favor**: Sin calificar.
> - **Alguien**: Sin calificar.
> - **Urgente**: Sin calificar.
> - **Hola/Saludos**: Sin calificar.

Comment: me parece bien acumularlas en algún sitio, pero también opino que el análisis debe ser más extenso. "Por favor", "alguien", "necesito" son palabras muy comunes en texto y no especialmente indican nada _malo_. Sería cuestión de analizar la presencia de cada una en títulos, cuerpos de pregunta, así como si se debe poner advertencia o prohibición. Para ser resolutivos y que no se enganche el tema, sugiero que cada solicitud se presente en una pregunta específica, para así poder ir a los CM y pedir su implementación con el aval de los votos.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con lo que dices, la idea de este post es solo acumular las propuestas, no es para pedir que todas esas palabras sean prohibidas a la vez. Es una referencia a todas las palabras propuestas en estas publicaciones, para ir acumulandolas e ir poco a poco

Comment: Propongo "urgente": Ninguna pregunta debería ser más urgente que las demás.

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: "Soy nuevo" es otra

Comment: No veo por que "ejercicio" está en la lista, no veo el problema. Si la persona que plantea la pregunta debe de especificar que indicaciones le dieron (el profesor o yo que sé) no debe de haber problema, **mientras cumpla los requisitos para que sea una pregunta válida y busque solución a un problema en especifico.** En mi opinión.

Comment: @gcoronel99 normalmente las preguntas que tienen en el título *ejercicio* suelen ser de baja calidad, tienes razón que si está bien redactada no habría problema, pero en mi opinión, puede poner que es un ejercicio en la descripción, no en el título. El titulo es para describir el problema no para decir que es un ejercicio, por ejemplo *Excepcion de clase x al llamar a la función* y en la descripción *Estoy realizando un ejercicio ... que me da el error x, lo que tengo es...*

Comment: @aeportugal es una palabra compuesta, aparte **nuevo** creo que puede ser válido en un título

Comment: @NicolasOñate concuerdo

Comment: Otra palabra que añadir: [hola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/376528/2742).

Comment: `TITULOS EN MAYÚSCULAS`. Por favor. Prohibidos, y un -1 automático.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con todos, hay algunas palabras que hacen que los titulos sean menos descriptivos. Y todas estas palabras podrían usarse en el cuerpo de la pregunta sin problema c:

Comment: Por otro lado, la palabra "urgente" para mi debería de ser prohibida en toda sección de la pregunta (titulo, descripción y etiquetas). Solo hace ruido y el tiempo de todos vale lo mismo aquí. No voy a darle más prioridad a x pregunta por que "es urgente".

Comment: @DanteS. creo recordar que ya hay algo al respecto

Comment: no hay justificacion de estas palabras en los titulos y denotan malas practicas de parte de loa desarrolladores novatos. estoy 110% de acuerdo con la propuesta. y tambien creo que esto debe aparecer en la ayuda como una explicacion en que preguntas evitar y repetidlo en como hacer una buena pregunta...

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent por ahora hemos logrado que [ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4846/101499) este prohibido con un enlace hacia [¿Cómo escribo un buen título?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4774/101499) poco a poco iremos mejorando el sitio para futuros usuarios :)