# ¿Cómo escribo un buen título?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, títulos-de-preguntas, propuesta-de-faq

> Esta es una traducción de la pregunta [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10647/209901)

Un buen título ayuda a que una pregunta reciba la atención que merece. ¿Qué debe contener un buen título?

[Regresar al índice del FAQ](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1378/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**1. Haz que el tema destaque.**

El objetivo del título es atraer a la gente interesada en tu tema o a aquellos que pueden darte una respuesta. La gente revisa las páginas de forma rápida; haz que sea fácil captar la atención de tu pregunta y entender de qué trata. Ten también en cuenta que hay gente que lee las preguntas a través de un [feed RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) <sup><sub>([por ejemplo el de SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/feeds))</sub></sup>, por lo que no verán ninguna etiqueta.

**2. Hazlo descriptivo, pero también concreto.**

Asegúrate de describir tu pregunta o problema de manera que los lectores entiendan la esencia de lo que trata ("Problema con función de Java" no es demasiado descriptivo). Sin embargo, no pongas *cada* detalle en el título... pues es en el cuerpo de la pregunta donde debes ponerlos. Haz tu título descriptivo pero también breve.

Por ejemplo, [este](http://www.useit.com/eyetracking) y [este](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/reading_pattern.html) artículos versan sobre cómo la gente lee las páginas web, basándose en sistemas de seguimiento del ojo para monitorizar usuarios. Para páginas de Stack Overflow, la gente en general lee la mayoría de las dos primeras entradas (las barras horizontales de la "F") y luego mira en diagonal el resto del texto, leyendo de media los primeros 16 caracteres de cada línea.

[image: Reading Heatmap]

**3. Usa la gramática adecuada y escribe en forma de pregunta.**

Asegúrate de escribir las palabras completa y correctamente. También, de redactar los títulos de manera que tengan sentido para la gente que los lea.

Asimismo, la [opinión experta](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), [el consenso en Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19999/should-question-titles-be-phrased-as-questions-a-straw-poll) y el [Centro de Ayuda de Stack Overflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) describen cómo se prefieren los títulos con gramática correcta y con forma interrogativa.

**4. No te preocupes por replicar una palabra de las etiquetas, si es posible**

Las etiquetas son ortogonales al título. Para distinguirla de las demás y evitar confusión o ambigüedad en el título, puede que tengas que usar alguna palabra clave de las etiquetas como parte del título.

Sin embargo, *no* añadas etiquetas explícitamente al título porque sí. Por ejemplo, no empieces el título con una etiqueta. Puedes leer [esta publicación](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) para mayor detalle sobre la relación entre las etiquetas y los títulos (por ejemplo, el título de la página siempre contendrá el nombre de la etiqueta más importante).

**Algunos buenos ejemplos**

A continuación puedes ver buenos títulos, extraídos de las publicaciones con mejor puntuación de los sitios principales.

Cada una de ellos resume la pregunta de forma adecuada sin introducir paja o palabrería innecesaria y, de forma crítica, proporciona *contexto* de lo que está preguntando exactamente.
<sub>(Nótese que algunas de estas preguntas son de sitios muy específicos como Ask Ubuntu o Physics)</sub>

- ¿Por qué se procesa más rápido un array ordenado que uno desordenado?
- ¿Puedo calcular la masa de una moneda basándome en el sonido de su caída?
- ¿Cómo deshago los más recientes *commit* de Git?
- ¿Existe algún pronombre neutral de género en singular (“his” vs. “her” vs. “their”)?
- ¿Cómo descomprimo un fichero zip desde la terminal?
- ¿Cómo instalo un fichero .deb a través de la línea de comandos?
- ¿Cómo sé si una variable de Bash está vacía?
- ¿Por qué los metales no se juntan cuando se tocan?
- ¿Cómo gestiono un servidor que ha sido comprometido?
- ¿En qué orden deberían verse las películas de Star Wars?
- ¿Cómo consigo Bash o ssh en un contenedor que está corriendo en background?
- ¿Cómo funcionan las subredes de IPv4?
- ¿Cómo actualizo un único paquete con apt-get?

**Algunos ejemplos malos**

Estos títulos, extraídos de publicaciones con poca puntuación, están construidos con fragmentos, no describen nada de la pregunta o carecen de contexto útil para saber *sobre qué se está preguntando realmente*:

- ¡Por favor, ayuda!
- Python: necesito ayuda sobre estadística
- PostgreSQL backups encriptados
- ¿Por qué funciona así?
- Sobre la arquitectura de la computadora
- ¿Construir imágenes usando markup HTML?
- Resolución DNS de una URL
- Combinar letras y números
- PHP - pasar variables
- BackgroundImage en css
- Map Routing, a la Google Maps?
- MySQL - Error en la sintaxis SQL
- No puedo escribir expresión en pascal
- valores 64-bit XML-RPC?
- ¿Apagar y encender Linux USB?

**5. Finalmente, sé flexible.**

Diferentes preguntas pueden beneficiarse de estilos diferentes de preguntas. Seguramente sea un error aplicar una regla única y rígida para todos ellos.