# Cuando edito una pregunta, ¿puedo editar el titulo?

Tags: discusión, ediciones, ediciones-sugeridas, títulos-de-preguntas

Me acabo de encontrar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/375333/quiero-saber-el-porqu%C3%A9-usando-apuntadores-esta-secci%C3%B3n-de-c%C3%B3digo-imprime-de-ma) y pienso que es una preguntota, ya que es una duda muy común. Esta pregunta es algo que la gente busca en Google.

Al principio solo iba a editar el código, porque estaba mal puesto. Sin embargo, considero que en el titulo el usuario puso lo que más bien tenía que ser el cuerpo de la pregunta. Ahora mi idea es editar titulo por **¿Por qué un apuntador sirve para imprimir un string?**, poner el titulo viejo como cuerpo y acomodar bien el código.

Mi pregunta es: **¿Es adecuado/debo de hacer esa edición? o más bien ¿Se aceptaría mi sugerencia de edición?**

Comment: Es una buena práctica para el sitio ya que se indexa mejor y así sirve como referencia de búsqueda para otra persona con la misma duda. Hay títulos como "Duda en python", "¿Por qué no funciona este código?" y similares, los he cambiado a la situación puntual del problema.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

¡Claro que sí! Los títulos deben describir el problema (más consejos en [¿Cómo escribo un buen título?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4774/83)) y las ediciones deben mejorar la pregunta.

Por lo que una edición que mejore la descripción de la pregunta siempre será bienvenida. Del privilegio [editar preguntas y respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit):

> **¿Cuándo debería editar publicaciones?**
>
> - ...
> - para clarificar el sentido de una publicación sin cambiarla