# Advertencia sobre la palabra "urgente" si esta está en el titulo y cuerpo de las preguntas

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, preguntas, advertencias-en-preguntas, filtros-de-calidad

Estube leyendo esta pregunta en Meta [Palabras en títulos que pueden derivar en preguntas de baja calidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4770/palabras-en-t%c3%adtulos-que-pueden-derivar-en-preguntas-de-baja-calidad).

Leyendo y comentando llegué a la conclusión de que la palabra "urgente" en una pregunta solo hace ruido. Al principio, pensé que sería buena idea prohibirla, pero que pasa si por la palabra se quiere usar en una pregunta como "Escribí en el input la palabra "urgente" y ocurrio x error"?

Mi propuesta es que si una pregunta tiene la palabra "urgente" en alguna parte, que aparezca una advertencia que diga algo como:

> Por favor, evita decir que buscas una respuesta urgentemente, esto
> puede ser visto como grosero y la comunidad no le dará mas prioridad a
> tu pregunta a pesar de que digas esto.

Que les parece? Debería de aparecer este aviso cuando alguien escribe la dichosa palabra?

Comment: A modo de sugerencia (no sé si aplica), podrías hacer que tu pregunta tenga un formato similar al de [Prohibamos la palabra “ayuda” en los títulos de las preguntas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4759).

Comment: No entiendo, a que formato te refieres @padaleiana? Al encabezado que dice de votar positiva y negativamente?

Comment: Me refería más bien a la etiqueta _característica-nueva_; y por lo que mencionaste, a eso iba yo con _no sé si aplica_.

Comment: Como me pude olvidar de esa etiqueta??? xd

Comment: Para mi si eso aplica, por que no aplicaría @padaleiana?

Comment: Simple _duda existencial_ :)

Comment: Gracias por avisarme lo de la etiqueta! Ya la agregué!