# Preguntas tipo: "¡Háganme el examen que me han mandado!"

Tags: discusión

Es raro que en algunos sitios de Stack Overflow, no esté la típica pregunta de: 
 *"¡Háganme el examen que me han mandado!"  
 o "¡Háganme este ejercicio...!"*

Les dejo rápidamente los problemas con este tipo de preguntas.

---

### Problemas con este tipo de preguntas

Pienso que ese tipo de preguntas deben de estar prohibidas por varias razones:

- Un programador debería de saber como resolver problemas.
- Son tan vagas, que ni siquiera dicen a que problema se enfrentan al resolver el ejercicio o algo por el estilo.
- No aprenderían a programar, ya que la programación se trata de resolver problemas...

*Hay muchos problemas más, pero creo que con esos son más que suficientes...*

**¿Qué piensan ustedes?**

Comment: Relacionado: [Exámenes, ejercicios y estudiantes caraduras](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4745/65), [¿Cómo gestionar las preguntas que son ejercicios de clase?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4365/65)